# the object is in the array but indexOf doesn't find dit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I'd like is to replace an element in the array of object $scope.users by another object.
I was thinking to do like this:

step 1 find the object I want to replace

```
var myValue;
myValue = $filter('filter')($scope.users,{email: "email"});
```

it gives me the object I want

step 2 EDIT: myValue now contains the exact object extracted from the array $scope.users, so now I'm going to look for it and find its index.

```
var index  = $scope.users.indexOf(myValue);
```

and this returns -1, so error...

$scope.users is like that

```
[Object { id=10, username="Eagle1", username_canonical="eagle1", more...}, Object { id=11, username="Pedro", username_canonical="pedro", more...}, Object { id=12, username="Carine", username_canonical="carine", more...}, Object { id=16, username="stephane", username_canonical="stephane", more...}, Object { id=17, username="throwError", username_canonical="throwerror", more...}]
```

and after the filter myValue is like that:

```
[Object { id=17, username="throwError", username_canonical="throwerror", more...}]
```

**EDIT: I solved it like this:**

```
var index = $scope.users.map(function(e){return e.keytofind}).indexOf("keytofind");
```

Comment: What is in $scope.users? What is in myValue?

Comment: Can you edit your question with an actual scenario: input -> expected output?

Comment: I added some data structure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume it is something like:

```
var elementPos = array.map($filter('filter')($scope.users,{email: "email"}))
                      .indexOf(idYourAreLookingFor);
var objectFound = array[elementPos];
```

Comment: Assuming "$scope.users" is array.

Comment: if $scope.users wan't an array I would have JS error wouldn't I ?

Comment: wasn't exactly what I needed. I've found the solution somewhere else but yours is correct actually